# Sacrifice enablers for EDH

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, mtg-commander

I'm building my first EDH deck and have chosen [Thraximundar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThraximundar%5d) (Grixis) as my general.

My deck has a lot of synergy centered around sacrificing creatures.  I find it easy to benefit from sacrificing and have plenty of targets for sacrificing but I need more ways of enabling the sacrifice triggers.

So far I have [Viscera Seer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bViscera%20Seer%5d), not much to go on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are tons of options:

[Attrition](http://magiccards.info/cmd/en/72.html) or [Blood Rites](http://magiccards.info/chk/en/159.html), while requiring to pay mana, would kill your opponents creatures (or the opponent himself in the case of the rites). If you need something that doesn't require mana to activate you could try [Bloodthrone Vampire](http://magiccards.info/m11/en/85.html), [Carrion Feeder](http://magiccards.info/pvc/en/2.html) or [Devouring Swarm](http://magiccards.info/m12/en/91.html).

[Hell's Caretaker](http://magiccards.info/9e/en/137.html) can be an interesting choice, because it gets creatures back when sacrificing others, but can be activated only once per turn.

[Lyzolda, the Blood Witch](http://magiccards.info/di/en/117.html) can be sweet, drawing you cards when sacrificing black creatures or dealing damage when sacrificing red ones.

There are lots more, [here](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3a%22sacrifice%20a%20creature%3a%22%20c!ubr&s=cname&v=card&p=1) you have Magiccards search of creatures that have an activated ability which requires to sacrifice a creature and are black, blue or red.

Comment: Thanks for all the options, its great to know this exchange has such dedicated members.

Answer (score 4):

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=+![G]+![W]&text=+[%22sacrifice%20a%20creature:%22]

Teach a man to fish.

The Gatherer is your friend. Once you know how to use it, you can find many of your own answers. You might want to examine the [Advanced Search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx) to narrow your search, or the [Help Page](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Help.aspx) to get an idea how to search. Explanation of the URL variables above ('?' starts the query, '&' separates variables, Left Hand Side (LHS) is the variable name, RHS is the value of the variable):

- action=advanced (gives responses for a greater range of variables)
- color=+![G]+![W] (card mana cost does NOT ('!') contain Green AND does NOT contain White mana)
- text=[%22sacrifice%20a%20creature:%22] (contains the exact RULES TEXT ('"' is %22, space is %20. URLs cannot contain these special characters, so they must be encoded) "sacrifice a creature:"

You can type your own search examples on the Advanced page, and then examine the URL to see exactly how your query is posted to the database. Technically, this search result would possibly show us cards that don't match the color identity of the Commander, if a card existed that contained a [G] or [W] activated ability, but not a whole lot of these exist. So just for fun, try replacing the RULES TEXT with this search strings.

- text=+![B]+[%22Sacrifice%20a%20creature:%22] This will return all sacrifice a creature activated abilities on cards that don't contain Black Mana symbols on the card. You will note that the botto of page 0 is **Quagmire Druid** which doesn't match our Commander's color identity.

Comment: I agree with this answer completely, but partly because I feel like I already posted it! ;)  Good work explaining how to put together a useful Gatherer query though - this is definitely a useful expansion of my answer.

Comment: While a regular user of gatherer I have never seen an explanation of how to use the advanced search strings, until now, thanks :) credit to @thesunneversets for getting there first.

Answer (score 3):

Although I generally shy away from suggesting a single card, in this case [Braids, Cabal Minion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=29947) fits the bill so perfectly that it's tough to ignore.

Comment: According to the 'Deck Construction' section of the rules at [mtgcommander.net](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php) [Braids, Cabal Minion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=29947) may not be used in the EDH format.

Comment: Whoops, to clarify, Braids may be used just not as a **Commander**.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at cards that make each player sacrifice creatures/permanents.

Examples: Pox, smallpox, smokestack, innocent blood, fleshbag marauder.

Answer (score 2):

[http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+[%22sacrifice%20a%20creature%22]](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=%20%5B%22sacrifice%20a%20creature%22%5D)

Without wishing to suggest specific decks for you, the above link should at least give you plenty of ideas to get your creative juices going!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, deck advice is always welcome but I much prefer finding the cards and building a theme myself, looking at deck lists for inspiration is... acceptable :)

Comment: This is the above search further refined not to include any cards costing white or green mana, by the way: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=+![W]+![G]&text=+[%22sacrifice%20a%20creature%22]

Answer (score 1):

Most Thrax decks I've seen use [Grave Pact](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247142) or [Butcher of Malakir](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247537). These are good "rattlesnake" cards that also greatly magnify the value of anything you feed to a sacrifice outlet. [Attrition](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247522) is also worth mentioning, since it's such a cheap outlet with one of the best beneficial effects. Consider [Malfegor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247179) and [Death Cloud](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50647) if you want additional bulk effects of this type.

Sacrificing your own dudes for mana is also pretty awesome because you can often turn that mana into more dudes to sacrifice. [Phyrexian Altar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=23226) and [Ashnod's Altar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=11158) serve as the basis for many token-sacrifice engines. [Skirk Prospector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=243465) can do the same for Goblins, as can [Basal Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=108792) for Slivers. Cards that create Eldrazi Spawn -- in particular, repeating ones like [Pawn of Ulamog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194907) and [Rapacious One](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247399) -- are also good for giving you a bit of extra mana while Thrax has something to munch on.

In my Sheoldred reanimator deck, I actually use fatties as sacrifice victims, feeding them to [Soldevi Adnate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3090), [Miren, the Moaning Well](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=88807), and [Xathrid Demon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189885).

[Minion Reflector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=174796) is an excellent way to get double value out of ETB triggers. The tokens it creates have a built-in self-sacrifice effect, but you might as well feed them to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Found a few that I have somewhere in my collection that look like good options:

[Carrion Feeder](http://magiccards.info/query?q=!Carrion%20Feeder)

[Phyrexian Ghoul](http://magiccards.info/query?q=!Phyrexian%20Ghoul)

Thanks for all the suggestions there are far more cards suited enabling sacrifices than I thought.